# Tile server fail to display map

Tags: postgis, vector-tiles, osm2pgsql

I ma begining with vector tiles and geo data in general. I am running a T-rex server to serv data post a postGIS database. i have an issue with my browser part because i can't display anything ! Something should be wrong with my .toml config file. [image: Here is the eror]

Comment: Welcome to GIS Stackexchange. Error messages should be posted as text, not as a screenshot. Also what have you tried to fix it? Does your table (planet_osm_point) have a "wkb_geometry" column? Because the error message says it does not

Comment: hello, my bad on this one, i'll fix it. I've fixed my import with osm2pgsql was wrong. I am facing new problems about the base map.